# Updated/Latest Published content not coming through from Broker DB for only one language

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.5

In our implementation, we have three languages for the website, say EN, AR, ZH. The published content comes up correctly on AR & ZH websites, but not EN. It only happens with sections like Footer, Navigation JSON, or when we display dynamic components.

Once we restart Web Application in IIS and restart Content Service, it comes through. It only happens on Production Servers, but not in lower environments. We have disabled SDL Web Cache, and any Object Cache in Deployer, Discovery & Session Content Services.

The only cache that we have now is service caching in Web.Config file, but I don't think that should impact only EN Website. It should impact all three. The caching is set to 1 hour, but the changes don't come up until we restart IIS Website and Content Service.

We are using SDL Web 8.1 & .NET DXA 1.5. Can anyone please guide where I can look more to investigate this issue?

Please see the below logs for navigation.json file. It seems that it is getting the navigation model from cache. How can I disable this?

```
2019-02-05 13:50:26,854 [21] DEBUG - Deserializing Navigation Model from raw content URL '/en/navigation.json'
2019-02-05 13:50:26,863 [21] DEBUG - Obtained Navigation Model from cache.
2019-02-05 13:50:26,864 [21] DEBUG - Obtained Navigation Model from cache.
```

Comment: Look at the localization resolver for publication mapping for English website area? if you directly access the footer and headers of English website URLs how it looks those responses is it still same, somewhere your publication id in your  webrequestcontext.localization is not switching correctly?

Comment: Is that whole english website pages not working or just the header and footer section only?

Comment: Hi Velmurugan, I have checked these as well, and they are also not coming updated. Even the Navigation JSON as well. The code is same in all environments and it works fine in lower ones, like UAT, SIT/QA.

Comment: The dynamic sections, like navigation json, header, footer, any dynamic components list etc.
These don't get updated when we publish, and only on EN Website.

Comment: Also, any DB caching is completely removed from cd_storage_conf.xml files of Deployer, Discovery & Session Content Services, and the services are restarted as well. I would have assumed that the LB Caching would have impacted it, but it is not working with direct host entry as well with a secondary URL Mapping in IIS, which is not public and restricted to server only.

Comment: Also, I have checked all configuration in Web.Config file of application, and the config files of micro-services. They don't have any setting related to EN Publication ID specifically.

Comment: 1. Did you check that published items exist in broker db?, 2. Try to run your webapp code locally pointing to your PROD discovery and check if it's works or not? 3. Enable fiddler on your system and capture the CIL request URLs and try it with postman to see those calls are working fine and find out goes with correct publication Id and URLs?

Comment: Yes, the items exists, as when we restart the Website IIS and Content Service, they appears on the website, without the need of republishing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88291/discussion-between-velmurugan-and-sharad-kumar-sangal).

Comment: It seems that the content service is not looking for this items again in Broker DB. Not sure what caching is blocking it do so, and strangely for only one locale.

Comment: If you enable DEBUG level logging (in Log.config), you will get diagnostic messages about DXA cache misses, this helps to analyze whether the problem lies in DXA caching or not.

Comment: I have added the logs, after enabling DEBUG level logging. It seems that it is getting the Navigation Model from Cache. This only happens for EN language, not others. Is there any way, I can disable this caching?

Comment: I have further investigated this issue, and found that the DXA Service Caching is responsible for this. In DEBUG Logs, I can see that the Navigation is fetched from cache. When I disable it, then it works fine. However, can any one suggest, on how I can bypass this in code, if I want some dynamic content types to come from Broker rather than Caching. I don't wish to totally disable it. Also, why this is working only for one locale. I have three locales setup, and for other two, content never comes from cache.

Comment: @SharadKumarSangal did you find a solution for this ? Please reply the solution found for this issue

Comment: @Arvind thiag No, we didn't find any solution for this yet. We even contacted Sitecore Support for help, but no success from there as well. It  seems the limitation on SDL Web 8 with DXA 1.5. We have to finally disable dxa service cache in order to resolve this issue. This is not advisable, but we had no other option left.